# Creating a default Security login page for my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot admin server but i want to include a spring security using the spring boot starter security dependency to create a login page. When i put my credentials username and password i get the error of this application has no explicit mapping for error. From what i saw i tried including thymeleaf dependency to resolve this problem but it didn't work. Please tell me what i am missing.

```
package com.example.demo;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}   

    @Configuration
public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login.html", "/**/*.css", "/img/**", "/third-party/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

        http.httpBasic();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Springboot Admin server already have the login page and no explicit template has to be created for it. Although i believe that it should be customizable but haven't gone deep into it. Below is my working solution for Springboot admin with default login page.

Main Application class

```
@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdminApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring security configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  
    private final String adminContextPath;
    public WebSecurityConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
    }   
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
        successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(adminContextPath + "/");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and()
                .logout().logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .ignoringAntMatchers(
                        adminContextPath + "/instances",
                        adminContextPath + "/actuator/**"
                );
    }
}
```

Credentials to login on Admin server is defined in application.properties as

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=Admin#123
```

Let me know if that helps.

**EDIT :** I tried to replicate scenario using the files you provided. It was pom.xml that had some missing dependencies. On resolving it, i can login into admin server successfully. Can you update your pom as below and retry. Please refer the comments i added in pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version> <!-- EspringDev CHANGED this version -->
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>admin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.2</spring-boot-admin.version> <!-- EspringDev CHANGED this version -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <!-- EspringDev ADDED below 2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
      <!-- dependencies -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, after implementing your spring security configurations now when i insert the credentials to login to the server it does not enter the spring boot admin application rather it stays on the login page. I tried making a custom login page to see if i can troubleshoot my problem but i got the same error as before which is no explicit mapping for /error. Yesterday i tried a different spring security configuration and it worked for logging in to the application, but it caused an issue with logging out that leads to an error.

Comment: My spring admin application has just these 3 files and it works perfectly. Can you share any other configuration Java class and application property file being used in your project

Comment: above is all the files in my project

Comment: Sure, thanks for the files. It looks good so it should be minor configuration mistake. I will surely look into it tomorrow. Apologies for delay

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time in solving my problem, much appreciated. I noticed that you changed the parent version and i was wondering why.

Comment: As per stackoverflow guidelines, please accept this as answer as this resolved your problem. Your effort will help others facing similar issues